# Connection timeout via AlwaysOn Listener IP on local computer

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, connectivity, listener

I have AlwaysOn availability group and it has one Listener IP.
I can connect this instance using Listener name but, cannot connect using Listener IP from my local computer. It returns following error

> *"Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=18013; handshake=14215;"*

When I try to connect this instance from another remote server, both of them are works!

Is there any problem on my local computer?

Comment: Is tcp/ip enabled ?

Comment: Yes, of course. It is enabled since sql server installation date on server.

Comment: Windows firewall enabled and blocking?

Comment: So you can connect to the hostname for the listener but not the ipaddress ?

Comment: If you open a command prompt and check the name lookup, is it the same IP returned? `nslookup listenerName`

Comment: Yes, I can connect with listener name but I cannot connect with IP adress. Yes, when I check from command prompt, it returns same IP adress.

Comment: Firewall state is off.

Comment: Perhaps a different port number?